# Editing Android TextView after populating TableView from db seems not possible

Tags: android, database, textview

In my View I have a table with two text views, and a button definded in my /layouts/main.xml. The rest of the table is created dynamically by a db query.
It all works fine except that: I'd like to change the text color of the two text views depending on how options are set. -> this works, but only as long as I don't populate the table with the db query.

To populate the table I use this:

```
public void DisplayTableRow(Cursor c)
{           
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.TableLayoutMain2);

    do {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow(this);
        tr.setId(i);
        TextView txt = new TextView(this);
        txt.setText(c.getString(c
                .getColumnIndex(myDatabaseAdapter.KEY_NAME)));
        txt.setId(j);
        txt.setTextSize(20);            
        tr.addView(txt);            
        table.addView(tr);          
    } while (c.moveToNext());       
}
```

And my main.xml looks like this: You will notice that I have created two TableLayouts this was to prevent the error I'm struggeling with. But it didn't help or do harm.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">



    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tr1">
                <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/Umtsstatus1"
            android:text="3G status" ></TextView>

        <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/wifistatus1"
            android:text="Wifi Status"></TextView>

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow android:id="@+id/tr3">
        <Button android:text="@string/add_alarm" android:id="@+id/add_alarm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_weight="1"></Button>
    </TableRow>

    </TableLayout>
    <TableLayout android:id="@+id/TableLayoutMain2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TableLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

To change the textView I do: (and this is what doesn't work after calling DisplayTableRow() )

```
public void showNetworkStatus(){
final SharedPreferences setting = OptionsActivity.getSettings(this);
final Boolean UmtsStatus = setting.getBoolean("radioButton3g", false);
final Boolean WifiStatus = setting.getBoolean("radioButtonWifi", false);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Toast.makeText(this,"3G Status: "+UmtsStatus,

              Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); //just to make sure...

TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Umtsstatus1); 
if (UmtsStatus.booleanValue())
    t.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else
    t.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);

TextView t2=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.wifistatus1); 
if (WifiStatus.booleanValue())
    t2.setTextColor(Color.RED);
else
    t2.setTextColor(Color.GREEN);
```

}

Comment: Did you try to clean the Project from Eclipse? (Project -> Clean)

Comment: Yes I did and still couldn't get it to work properly.

Comment: I have tried to reduce the layout to just one button and the table (all in a table layout and seperated in rows with individual ID's) and could get it to work fine in the emulator. But it doesn't work on my galaxy.. the screen stays just blank.:(