# TableView from SQL with OnClickListener

Tags: android, sql, tableview, clickable

I've been searching and found some Questions, but not the one I want to ask. [First](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209561/tableview-in-android), [second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968226/show-data-in-table-view-in-android) and not so for my theme [third one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8543647/editing-android-textview-after-populating-tableview-from-db-seems-not-possible) provided me some help, but not at all.

I want to make a tableview which is populated from database with dbquery. Every tablerow contains three textviews, first and last column are 4-digit numbers and last one is a String around 30 letters.

All of that I can manage somehow. The problem is that I want to make every row a clickable element. I have a dream about using an cursorAdapter first to populate and then for OnClickListener but as far as I know there is nothing like this for tableviews. And gridView is not a solution for me, because I need to have first and last column much more narrow than the middle one. At least I didn't find the way to do this in gridview.

Do You have any idea?
If You need some additional info, please ask me and I'll do my best.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/**
 * Call once per row.
 * 
 * @param data
 *            Text containing data for each cell.
 * @param rowId
 *            unique id for OnClickListener
 */
public void addRow(String[] data, int[] rowId) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        TextView tv = getTextViewAndMakeThemPretty(data[i]);
        tv.setId(rowId[i]);
        tv.setFocusable(false);
        tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /**
                 * Do your stuff here.
                 */

            }
        });
        this.addView(tv);
        /**
         * Adds the TextView to Row as Cell
         */
    }
}
```

You have to extend TableRow and add this code to it. Call this when you need to add the row and pass in the data in the first params.